# I'm getting this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'word_index'

Tags: python, nlp, tensorflow2.0

Even tho when i print sentence it prints the number of strings seprated by comma's
Here is my code :-

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import json

sentence = []
urls = []
labels = []

data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('Sarcasm_Headlines_Dataset.json', 'r')]
for item in data:
    sentence.append(item["headline"])
    urls.append(item['article_link'])
    labels.append(item['is_sarcastic'])
    
print(sentence)
tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token="<00V>")
tokenizer = tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentence)
word_index =tokenizer.word_index
```

Comment: `fit_on_texts` returns `None`, try instead calling `tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentence)` without assigning its return value to `tokenizer`

Answer (score 0):

`fit_on_texts` is in-place operation and it will return `None`

instead of:

```
tokenizer = tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentence)
```

use:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token="<00V>")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentence)
word_index =tokenizer.word_index
```